# Почему Стандартный AlertDialog дает такой результат

Tags: java, android

```
AlertDialog.Builder quitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            ActivityFragments.this);
    quitDialog.setTitle("Выход: Вы уверены?");

    quitDialog.setPositiveButton("Таки да!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    quitDialog.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    quitDialog.show();
```

Данный код помещает неравномерно кнопки и текст в Диалоге.
Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это совершенно нормальное поведение диалога.

Comment: @post_zeew, как сделать все ровно?

Comment: @MartinezToni, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797134/how-to-use-and-style-the-new-alertdialog-from-appcompat-22-1-and-above кастомные стили для алерта

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131133/right-justify-text-in-alertdialog тут конкретно с выравниванием текста в AlertDialog

Comment: @МихаилРебров в моем случае проще заменить AlertDialog, на Dialog со своей разметкой?

Comment: @Martinez Toni, мне сложно сказать что для Вас будет проще. Все мы разные. Лично для меня - всё одно и я бы смотрел на контекст и на то понадобятся мне стили и разметка в будущем в этом проекте. Из этого бы и исходил. Переделать тоже никогда не поздно при желании. Иногда я исхожу из соображений: что лично для меня интереснее или полезнее в качестве развития.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы наблюдаете - стандартный вид диалога в Material стиле. Заголовок жирный слева вверху, кнопки - справа внизу. При использовании стандартного диалога он будет отображаться по разному на разных версиях ОС. Если вам нужна какая-то определённая разметка или вы хотите чтобы оно одинаково выглядело на всех версиях ОС - вам нужно собственную разметку составить и отображать её в диалоге.

Если вас устроит показанный вами внешний вид, то вот отличная либа которая на всех версиях ОС отображает диалоги одинаково:

[Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)